# Search in two tables and combine results with PDO

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables named **companies** and **jobs**. They are related - jobs table has a foreign key **company_id**.

**company** table columns are: companyname, city, province etc.

**jobs** table columns: title, department, description etc

I want to search both tables in those columns and if the keyword has a match in **jobs** table get the related data from the **company** table, and if the match is in the **company** table, I want to get all the jobs related to the company.

As far as I know in order to search in both tables I have to use UNION, this works:

```
$sql= "(SELECT title, department FROM  jobs WHERE title LIKE ? ) 
UNION 
(SELECT companyname,city FROM  companies WHERE companyname LIKE ?)";
```

I dont know how to get related data from the other table depending on the match. Is it possible with just one call using JOIN?

Thanks.

Comment: Use company_id in where condition if you have company_id in both table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JOIN` and `OR` condition:

```
SELECT jobs.title, jobs.department,
companies.companyname, companies.city
FROM jobs 
JOIN companies ON companies.id = jobs.company_id
WHERE (jobs.title LIKE ? OR companies.companyname LIKE ?)
```

With `UNION`:

```
SELECT jobs.title, jobs.department,
companies.companyname, companies.city
FROM jobs 
JOIN companies ON companies.id = jobs.company_id
WHERE jobs.title LIKE ?

UNION

SELECT jobs.title, jobs.department,
companies.companyname, companies.city
FROM jobs 
JOIN companies ON companies.id = jobs.company_id
WHERE companies.companyname LIKE ?
```

Comment: Thank you! I got it, no need for UNION, simple JOIN is enough.

Comment: `UNION` would perform better.

Comment: It works with UNION too, but the two parts look the same except the WHERE condition. Does it really perform better?

Comment: In common case, yes, but it depends on engine type and version and of course it depends on presense of indexes in table

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT a.title, a.department,c.companyname, c.city
FROM a 
JOIN c ON c.id = a.company_id
WHERE (a.title LIKE 'title' OR c.companyname LIKE 'companyname')
```